# jquery scroll event not being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wanted to get the scroll method and load somthing while scrolling happens .
its not working properly
maybe because my elements are being added to the page dynamically.
however i see the existance of the elements but its not working programmatically.
and while i add these methods into my chrome's console then it start to work.
idk how to solve it.

```
        

    $(document).ready(function () {
                ////First Method
                $(".convHistory").on('scroll', function () {
            console.log('Event Fired');
        });
        
        ////Second Method
        $(".convHistory").bind('scroll', function () {
                console.log('Event worked');
                }); 

        
        ////Third Method
        document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
            if (event.target.className.includes("convHistory")) {  
                console.log('scrolling', event.target);
            }
        }, true /*Capture event*/);
        
        


                //forth method
        $('.convHistory').scroll(function () {
            console.log('Event worked');

        });
        
        
        
        


    });
```

Comment: I have updated the event binding code in answer. Try that

Answer (score 0):

As your elements are dynamic, bind events for dynamic elements like this:-

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.convHistory', function () {
     console.log('Event worked');
});
```

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: @Mamadmti what is the error? And if there is no error. Just add html also . So I test by myself

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, the elements are binding dynamically, you have to do something like below

```
div.append(yourElement class="convHistory");
```

then after that

```
$(".convHistory").on('scroll', function () {
    console.log('Event Fired');
});
```

Comment: This is how I do, surely there are many other ways to do this

Comment: no it still doesnt work !!

Comment: it works only on chrome's console but it doesnt work on my code